# AWS JAVA SDK CLI : java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am making an API call , and I am trying to do that through sts assume-role API.

My Java program is :

```
STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider  = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider(credentials,"arn:aws:iam::093937234853:role/CapOne-CrossAccount-CustomRole-ReadOnly","123");
ec2Client.setRegion(getRegion());
this.setDescribeInstancesResult(ec2Client.describeInstances());
```

In credentials variable above I am passing my secret id and key.
The error I am getting is :

```
Sep 23, 2015 3:25:48 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

Untill I was using the STSAssume role , It was working fine . But due to a requiremnt I have to use roles. So I am sure , my credentials variables is being set properly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was not setting my proxy parameter properly , after setting that , it started working :

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfiguration.setProxyHost("proxy.kdc.capitalone.com");
    clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(8099);
    clientConfiguration.setProxyUsername("EID");
    clientConfiguration.setProxyPassword("PWD");
    clientConfiguration.setPreemptiveBasicProxyAuth(false);
```

Comment: So in other words you didn't post the complete code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: No , if you see the first line of my code , I am not passing the client configuration over there . But yes i agree I should have provided more information.